# Average of multiple stacks

Tags: image-processing, imagej

How can I average multiple stacks in one go? Ideally using a GUI tool like ImageJ? I want to do this on sets of about 10-20 stacks: 1500x1500pixels, 500 slices,  1 channel in each stack. Loading all of them at once would be pushing the limits of my RAM.

As an output, I want one stack (1500x1500pixels, 500 slices, 1 channel) with the intensities averaged across the different stacks.

ImageJ seems limited to averaging 2 stacks at once.

I would like equal weight for all stacks in the final average.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally using a GUI tool like imageJ?

Questions regarding *usage* of ImageJ and not related to any piece of code are off-topic on stackoverflow.com and should be best asked on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

> How can I average multiple stacks in one go?

In ImageJ, you can build a **[hyperstack](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-8.html#toc-Section-8)** from your stacks (e.g. by using *Image > Stacks > Tools > Concatenate...* and then *Image > Hyperstacks > Stack to Hyperstack...*) and subsequently create an average projection (*Image > Stacks > Z Project...*). 
To achieve your task, you should assign the 500 slices per stack to the *t* dimension, and the dimension to be averaged should be *z*.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have too many stacks to combine them all into one large hyperstack. I am running out of memory.

I ended up using python instead:

```
import tkFileDialog
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
from tifffile import imsave

#select a directory containing tif-stacks to process
#tif-stacks must have equal dimensions

sd=tkFileDialog.askdirectory()

#list of files to process
fl= glob.glob(os.path.join(sd,'*.tif'))

#number of files to process
n_files=np.shape(fl)[0]

im = Image.open(fl[0])

#get number of frames in first file by seeking all frames until error occurs
#this seems clunky but is very fast
#assuming same number of frames for all files
n = 0
while True:
    n += 1
    try:
        im.seek(n)
    except:
        break
n_frames=n

#loop through all images,
#read each frame and accumulate frame-wise sum over all stacks

w, h = im.size
temp = np.zeros( (h,w,n_frames), dtype=np.int32 )

for i in range(n_files):
    print 'processing file: ', i
    im = Image.open(fl[i])

    for n in range (n_frames):
        curframe = np.array(im.getdata()).reshape(h,w)
        temp[:,:,n] += curframe
        im.seek(n)
        print ['frame: ', n],"         \r",

avgStack=temp/n_files
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted jlarsch's code above a bit, because it did not run in python3. Here is my solution:

```
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import os
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    from tifffile import imwrite, imread

    #select a directory containing tif-stacks to process
    #tif-stacks must have equal dimensions

    sd=filedialog.askdirectory()
    fl = glob.glob(os.path.join(sd, '*.tif'))

    #list of files to process
    fl= glob.glob(os.path.join(sd,'*.tif'))

    #number of files to process
    n_files=np.shape(fl)[0]
    #get number of frames in first file by seeking all frames until error occurs
    #this seems clunky but is very fast
    #assuming same number of frames for all files
    with Image.open(fl[0]) as im:
        h,w=im.size
        n = 0
        while True:
            n += 1
            try:
                im.seek(n)
            except:
                break
        n_frames = n

    #loop through all images,
    #read each stack and append to a 4-dimensional numpy array

    w, h = im.size
    temp = np.empty((0,n_frames,h,w), dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(n_files):
        stack = imread(fl[i])
        temp = np.append(temp, stack[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)
    #average over all stacks
    average=np.mean(temp,axis=0)

    
    imwrite('average.tif', average)
```